# Spring Batch with 2 Couchbase clusters

Tags: spring, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to create a `Spring Batch` in order to copy Couchbase data from one cluster to another. I'm using `Spring Data Couchbase`.

But I can't figure out how to have 2 different repositories on 2 different clusters.

I've found many examples on how to have multiple buckets on the same cluster based on `OperationsMapping` but it does'nt meet my needs because in my case the Data Model is the same.

When I use the second repository (the target where the bucket is empty) to test if the document from the source repository exists, I get `true`. So it seems the test is made in the same repository (the source).

I tried to declare custom beans with custom names for `CouchbaseTemplate`, `CouchbaseClientFactory`, `CouchbaseClusterEnvironment` and `CouchbaseCluster` with no luck.

Thanks for help !

Here is the example of one of my 2 configuration classes (the second is the same with 'source' replaced by 'target') :

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = SourceDocumentRepository.class, couchbaseTemplateRef = "sourceCouchbaseTemplate")
public class SourceCouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

  ... getters overriden : connectionString, user, pwd, bucket, scope

  @Bean(name = "sourceCouchbaseCluster", destroyMethod = "disconnect")
  public Cluster sourceCouchbaseCluster(ClusterEnvironment sourceCouchbaseClusterEnvironment) {
    return Cluster.connect(getConnectionString(), ClusterOptions.clusterOptions(authenticator()).environment(sourceCouchbaseClusterEnvironment));
  }

  @Bean(name = "sourceCouchbaseClusterEnvironment", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
  public ClusterEnvironment sourceCouchbaseClusterEnvironment() {
    ClusterEnvironment.Builder builder = ClusterEnvironment.builder();
    builder.jsonSerializer(JacksonJsonSerializer.create(couchbaseObjectMapper()));
    configureEnvironment(builder);
    return builder.build();
  }
  
  @Bean("sourceCouchbaseClientFactory")
  public CouchbaseClientFactory sourceCouchbaseClientFactory() {
    return new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(getConnectionString(), authenticator(), getBucketName(), getScopeName());
  }

  @Bean("sourceCouchbaseTemplate")
  public CouchbaseTemplate sourceCouchbaseTemplate() {
    return new CouchbaseTemplate(sourceCouchbaseClientFactory(), new MappingCouchbaseConverter());
  }

  @Bean("sourceReactiveCouchbaseTemplate")
  public ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate sourceReactiveCouchbaseTemplate() {
    return new ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(sourceCouchbaseClientFactory(), new MappingCouchbaseConverter());
  }
  
  @Bean("sourceCouchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping")
  public RepositoryOperationsMapping sourceCouchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping(CouchbaseTemplate sourceCouchbaseTemplate) {
    return new RepositoryOperationsMapping(sourceCouchbaseTemplate);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was about to post that it isn't possible until a colleague pointed me to this blog.  https://burakcanekici.medium.com/connecting-multiple-buckets-in-a-spring-application-f2d7f6820f60

I haven't had a chance to investigate it.

Comment: Thanks I've seen it but it doesn't work because, as I said, solutions based on OperationsMapping does not meet my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating one repository for my source based on `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration` with my custom findBy with pagination.

And for the target, I created a simple configuration class with custom names for the beans :

```
@Configuration
public class TargetCouchbaseConfiguration {
  
  @Autowired
  private CopyCouchbaseDataProperties properties;

  @Autowired
  public MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter;
  
  private Authenticator authenticator() {
    return PasswordAuthenticator.create(properties.getTarget().getUsername(), properties.getTarget().getPassword());
  }

  public ObjectMapper couchbaseObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.registerModule(new JsonValueModule());
    return mapper;
  }

  @Bean(name = "targetCouchbaseClusterEnvironment", destroyMethod = "shutdown")
  public ClusterEnvironment targetCouchbaseClusterEnvironment() {
    ClusterEnvironment.Builder builder = ClusterEnvironment.builder();
    builder.jsonSerializer(JacksonJsonSerializer.create(couchbaseObjectMapper()));

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(properties.getKeyStoreLocation())) {
      SecurityConfig.Builder securityConfigBuilder = SecurityConfig.builder()
          .enableHostnameVerification(false)
          .enableTls(true)
          .trustStore(Paths.get(properties.getKeyStoreLocation()), null, Optional.of(Constants.JKS_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE));
  
      builder.ioConfig(IoConfig.networkResolution(NetworkResolution.EXTERNAL))
        .securityConfig(securityConfigBuilder);
    }
    
    return builder.build();
  }
  
  @Bean(name = "targetCouchbaseCluster", destroyMethod = "disconnect")
  public Cluster targetCouchbaseCluster(ClusterEnvironment targetCouchbaseClusterEnvironment) {
    return Cluster.connect(properties.getTarget().getConnectionString(), 
                           ClusterOptions.clusterOptions(authenticator()).environment(targetCouchbaseClusterEnvironment));
  }
  
  @Bean("targetCouchbaseClientFactory")
  public CouchbaseClientFactory targetCouchbaseClientFactory(Cluster targetCouchbaseCluster) {
    return new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(targetCouchbaseCluster, properties.getTarget().getBucket(), properties.getTarget().getScope());
  } 
  
  @Bean("targetCouchbaseTemplate")
  public CouchbaseTemplate targetCouchbaseTemplate(CouchbaseClientFactory targetCouchbaseClientFactory) {
    return new CouchbaseTemplate(targetCouchbaseClientFactory, mappingCouchbaseConverter);
  }
}
```

This way, I can use my `sourceRepository` and my `targetCouchbaseTemplate` in my app :

```
  @Autowired
  private SourceDocumentRepository sourceRepository;

  @Autowired
  private CouchbaseTemplate targetCouchbaseTemplate;
```